# Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name - django fix

Tags: django, django-urls, django-errors

When trying to create the get_absolute_url. Am geting this error, am not sure why since i searched and i saw many tutorials but couldnt figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the app name on the reverse for example.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('**eye**:article_detailed', kwargs={"slug":self.slug})
```

also if you want to display urls without going through get_absolute_url you can use

```
{% url "eye:article_detailed" articlesingle.slug %}
```

in  your template, and again you have to specify the app otherwise you get an error. At lease in my case.